# Multiple Engagement Split Pathways

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a need to create an engagement split that will look for one of 3 different links. Is there a way of doing this without having to create multiple Engagement activities for each link? We have a need of creating paths based on multiple clicks on different links and it is getting very messy with having to create multiple engagement split activities for one email.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can achieve this:

1- Add alias to your links in your emails

2- Create fields for these 3 links in your targeting DE. For example: LINK1 Text | LINK2 Text..

3- Create a query that checks whether a link in your email was clicked or not by a contact. It can be something like this:

```
SELECT 

LinkName AS Link_Clique,
SubscriberKey AS SubscriberKey 

FROM
(SELECT LinkName, c.SubscriberKey, eventdate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.SubscriberKey ORDER BY eventdate DESC) 
        AS Row
FROM _Click c
INNER JOIN YOUR_DE DE ON DE.SubscriberKey = c.SubscriberKey
WHERE 
LinkName <> 'YOUR_LINK1_ALIAS'
AND TriggeredSendCustomerKey = '1058' /* Your triggerSendCustomerKey */ 
 ) as s
 WHERE row=1
```

The query uses `TriggeredSendCustomerKey` so that it keeps working even if you create new versions of your Journey.

4- Use a decision split in your Journey and check on the values of your LINK1, LINK2,.. fields to create your pathways.